# npm - release module multiple branches with multiple versions

Tags: node.js, git, npm, git-branch, semantic-versioning

I have a npm module which is already released under `4.x.x` version and have breaking changes comparing to `3.x.x` stable version.

However I have some updates to `3.x.x` version and want to patch its' npm version. Is it possible? Can I manage 2 major versions on npm?

Will https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish `npm publish --tag` do the trick?

Answer (score 4):

> However I have some updates to 3.x.x version and want to patch its' npm version. Is it possible? Can I manage 2 major versions on npm?

Yes, it's possible. Something that's common is to have the `master` branch for new developement and branch off older versions if you want to patch them and name them e.g. `3.x`.

So if we assume your module has previously been released as `3.1.2` and you want to fix a bug, i.e. you want to publish `3.1.3` (patch release). Simply branch off from `3.1.2` (assuming you have a git tag `v3.1.1`):

```
git checkout v3.1.2
git checkout -b 3.x
# make changes and commit
npm version patch # will bump package.json, commit that and tag
npm publish
```

Comment: Will this work if you release a dev branch, e.g. if you want `npm install` to install version 3, but offer version 4 with an explicit "@4.x.x"?

Comment: Nope. Above will publish the _latest_ version of the module. If you want to publish other versions that aren't considered latest version (i.e. default when doing npm install) you need to use `--tag`. For example `npm publish --tag next`, this will enable users getting version 3 by default but need to do `npm install foo@4.0.0` to get that specific version. Makes sense?